# how to make an Image appear when the text(textview) is clicked.?

Tags: android

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/warning"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

how can i show image when i click a text (TextView)?

please use the id show_image

Comment: Android doesnt have a "mouse cursor"

Comment: i mean when the text is clicked or tap..sorry for that.. im a little bit confused because i'm using an emulator..^^ @Niza

Answer (score 0):

Appear where?
The `TextView` can show only text, to show an image you have to create an `ImageView` and use a listener on the `TexView` that onClick set the image in the `ImageView`

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourImageview..setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);

            }
        });
```

Comment: i want it to appear like Toast @Silverstorm